# cross platform "rm" command

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

I currently have the following script in my package.json for deleting all ".js" files in my bundles folder for when I run "npm run build". It works fine when running it in dev servers but breaks when it is run in a Windows machine.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm bundles/*.js && webpack",
  },
}
```

Since I am hashing all my build files, I am required to delete them all before adding new ones, such that I don't end up with a bunch of old builds.

Is there a "rm bundles/*.js" that would work in both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Macs are Unix so `rm` should work without issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Take a look at [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs):

> ShellJS is a portable (Windows/Linux/OS X) implementation of Unix
>   shell commands on top of the Node.js API. You can use it to eliminate
>   your shell script's dependency on Unix while still keeping its
>   familiar and powerful commands. You can also install it globally so
>   you can run it from outside Node projects - say goodbye to those
>   gnarly Bash scripts!

And further to [shelljs/shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx), which provides the following example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "shx rm -rf build dist && shx echo Done"
  }
}
```

**An alternative:**

You may also want to take a look at [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), both so called Task Runners. Gulp has [gulp-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean) and Grunt has [grunt-contrib-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-clean). Both aim to delete folders and/or files.

Let's take Grunt for example:

1. Add the Grunt CLI with `npm i -g grunt-cli` to your system
2. Add the needed packages to your project with `npm i --save-dev grunt grunt-contrib-clean`
3. Create a file named `gruntfile.js`
4. Add the following lines:

> ```
> module.exports = (grunt) => {
>   'use strict';
>
>   grunt.initConfig({
>     clean: ['bundles'],
>   });
>
>   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
>
>   grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean']);
> };
> ```

5. Update your script `"build": "grunt && webpack"`

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is no way of writing a command in my package.json that can run on both Mac and Windows?

Comment: npm's shx was perfect, thnx.

Comment: I tried this npm script: **"test": "tsc && shjs rm -rf testOutput"** but get **ShellJS: script not found (rm)**

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Try `shx` instead of `shjs`

Answer (score 46):

The npm package **rimraf** is available for command-line usage in `scripts`.

First install locally into your project:

```bash
$ npm install --save-dev rimraf
```

Then update the `build` script in your **package.json** file:

```json
"scripts": {
   "prebuild": "rimraf --glob 'bundles/*.js'",
   "build": "webpack"
}
```

The **rimraf** command (named after `rm -rf`) deletes the files.

Documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf#cli

**rimraf** is a well established project with over <s>3,000</s> <s>4,000</s> 5,000 ⭐s on GitHub.

**2023-03-04 Update:**
Added the `--glob` flag (introduced in **rimraf v4.2**), and single quoted the path parameter so the *glob* is interpreted by **rimraf** instead of the shell (important for cross-platform consistency).

Answer (score 15):

#### Cross-platform, no dependencies

If you're like me and don't want to add 11 dependencies just to delete a directory, you can use node exit codes to conditionally run scripts:

**e.g. Remove the ./dist folder**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "npm run clean:win && npm run clean:lin",
    "clean:win": "node -e \"if (process.platform === 'win32') process.exit(1)\" || , if exist dist rmdir /Q /S dist",
    "clean:lin": "node -e \"if (process.platform !== 'win32') process.exit(1)\" || rm -rf dist",
  }
}
```

```
npm run clean
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not concern about 'rm/del not found' console.log, here is the short and simple solution, no additional dependencies are required, **rm** works on Mac and Linux, **del** works on Windows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "(rm bundles/*.js || del bundles/*.js) && webpack",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: `recursive-fs` added a CLI for deleting a folder so you can now do:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "recursive-delete \"./bundles\""
}
```

**Original**:
If you decide you don't need 11 additional packages just to delete a single folder, you can use [recursive-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-fs) and a short script:

```
node -e \"require('recursive-fs').rmdirr(require('path').resolve('bundles'), ()=>{})\"
```

Alternatively, someone could write an NPM package that does this and has only a single dependency on `recursive-fs`, which would still put it at 9 packages fewer than rimraf.  Another option would be to fork `recursive-fs` and publish an NPM package that includes a CLI in it that makes using it for recursive deletions easier.